# Why is the following MySQL query generating error?

Tags: mysql, sql

The query was:

```
DELETE 
  FROM sql_invoicing.invoices
 WHERE client_id = 
 (SELECT client_id 
   FROM sql_store.customers 
  WHERE last_name = 'Smith')
```

In the above query the Database used has 'invoices' table in 'sql_invoicing' schema and 'customers' table is in 'sql_store' schema.

The error generated is :

> Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ('sql_invoicing'.'payments',CONSTRAINT 'fk_payment_invoice' FOREIGN KEY ('invoice_id') REFERENCES 'invoices' ('invoice_id') ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Pardon me if the question is naive, I am a beginner in MySQL.

Comment: The constraint on the payments table prohibits the orphaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a table that has a foreign key from payments table to the invoice table. when you delete an invoice, what do you want to happen to the payment row that's connected to it? you have `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, that means if the invoice id changes, the payment's invoice_id value would change to follow, but it doesn't tell it what to do if the invoice is deleted all together.

You can add `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which would delete the payment related to the invoice you deleted.

But I would highly suggest against hard deletes like this, especially for important data like invoices and payments. instead I'd suggest going with a soft delete approach, a simple way would be adding another column "deleted", and not retrieving the fields where deleted is true. But I'd suggest thinking about your project's idea in-depth, why is an invoice deleted? was it cancelled, refunded? your database should reflect that, and so should your application in its logic (e.g can't make a payment for a cancelled invoice)

Comment: The database I'm working with is a training data set, so no harm done however much I modify it, but still your comment also gave me an idea about how to actually think while woring with SQL, Thank You for the helpful answer. Cheers!